# A simple Mastermind game in C

Tags: beginner, c, game

Any idea to write this code more smarter and shorter? I also expect your advice about general organisation of the code.

> **Object of the Game**
>
> In your version of Mastermind, the computer will be the codemaker and one player will be the codebreaker. The computer picks a sequence of 4 pegs, each one being one of any of size colors.
>
> The object of the game is to guess the exact positions of the colors in the computer's sequence in as few guesses as possible. After each guess, the computer gives you a score of exact and partial matches.
>
> **Rules**
>
> 1. The sequence can contain pegs of colors: red, yellow, green, blue, white, black.
> 2. A color can be used any number of times in the sequence.
> 3. All four pegs of the secret sequence will contain a color - no blanks/empties are allowed.
> 4. Each guess must consist of 4 peg colors - no blanks.
> 5. The player has 12 guesses to find the secret sequence.
>
> **Scoring**
>
> For each of the pegs in your guess that is the correct color and in
>   the correct position, the computer will give you one small black peg to
>   the right of that move. If you score 4 small black pegs on a guess,
>   you have guessed the secret sequence.
>
> For each of the pegs in your guess that is a correct color in an incorrect position, the computer will give you one small white peg to the right of that move. Together, there will be no more than four small black and white pegs for each move.
>
> If none of the pegs in your guess is of a correct color, you will see no small pegs to the right of that move.
>
> **Sample scoring:**
>
> [image: Sample scoring]
>
> **Requirements:**
>
> 1. The players should be able to enter four colours as their guess. When they enter their guess, then your program should display their guess and next to the guess it should display the score. Make sure that you clearly visualise the guess and also the score next to it. You do not need to use graphics as long as you display the colours properly that will be enough.
> 2. Different visualisation approach can be used, for example in your program when you do the computation you can assign an integer number to each colour, but then you can visualise it as follows which is based on Figure 1:
>
>    ```
>    Your guess:              | Your score:
>    ---------------------------------------------------
>    Blue Yellow Green Red    | Black Black White White
>    ---------------------------------------------------
>    Black Yellow White Red   | Black White
>    ---------------------------------------------------
>    Yellow Blue White Yellow |
>    ```
> 3. After the player completes playing the came once (after either they win or they had 12 guesses), your program should ask the user if they would like to continue if they do then your program should generate a new code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>

void makeCode(char secretCode[4][10])
{
    int i, randColor;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)  
    {
        randColor = 1 + rand() % 6;     //creates a number 
        switch(randColor)       //converts number created to a string
        {
            case 1: strcpy(secretCode[i], "red");       break;
            case 2: strcpy(secretCode[i], "yellow");    break;
            case 3: strcpy(secretCode[i], "green");     break;
            case 4: strcpy(secretCode[i], "blue");      break;
            case 5: strcpy(secretCode[i], "white");     break;
            case 6: strcpy(secretCode[i], "black");     break;
        }
    }   
}

void guess(char guessCode[4][10])
{
    printf("\nEnter your guess:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        scanf("%s", guessCode[i]);  
}

void codeCheck(char secretCode[4][10], char guessCode[4][10], int *blackPeg, int *whitePeg)
{
    int i, j, checkSecret[4] = {1,1,1,1}, checkGuess[4] = {1,1,1,1};
    *blackPeg = *whitePeg = 0;

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)      //if secret and guess's position and color are same, blackpeg increases and mark "check"
        if(strcmp(guessCode[i], secretCode[i]) == 0)   
        {
            ++*blackPeg;
            checkSecret[i] = checkGuess[i] = 0;
        }            

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)       
            if(strcmp(secretCode[i],guessCode[j]) == 0  &&  checkGuess[i]  &&  checkSecret[j]  &&  i != j)        
            {// determines crushes and eliminates extra whitePegs 
                ++*whitePeg;
                checkSecret[j] = checkGuess[i] = 0;
            }
}

void displayGuess(char guessCode[4][10], int blackPeg, int whitePeg)
{   
    int i;
    printf("\nYour Guess\t\t\t\tYour Score\n");   
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) 
        printf("%s ", guessCode[i]); 
    printf("\t\t");        
    for(i=0; i<blackPeg; i++) 
        printf("black ");
    for(i=0; i<whitePeg; i++)
        printf("white ");       
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, option=1, blackPeg, whitePeg, wrongGuess;
    char secretCode[4][10], guessCode[4][10];
    while(1)
    {
        printf("MASTER MIND! \nPress 1 to start game \nPress any number to exit\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);        
        if(option == 1)
        {
            makeCode(secretCode);
            for(wrongGuess=1; wrongGuess<=12; wrongGuess++)      //gives 12 rights to guess
            {
                guess(guessCode);
                codeCheck(secretCode, guessCode, &blackPeg, &whitePeg);
                displayGuess(guessCode, blackPeg, whitePeg);
                if(blackPeg == 4)           //if player guess correct all, than the game finishes
                {
                    printf("You Win!\n\n\n\n");  break;
                }
            }
        if(wrongGuess == 13)        //if player cannot guess correct colors in 12 rounds, he losts
            printf("\nYou Lost!\nSecret Code: %s %s %s %s\n\n\n\n\n", secretCode[0], secretCode[1], secretCode[2], secretCode[3]);  
        }
        else
            exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy crap I played this game as a kid and I just now realized that the Fallout 3/4 style of computer terminal hacking is very very similar to this game.

Comment: How do you stop the repetitive color. I.e only one color in that one set code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Good

The choice of variable and function names is very descriptive.
The code is properly indented. The consistent use of camelCase is excellent.

### MAGIC NUMBERS

The term Magic Numbers refers to numerical constants in the code. A good programming practice is to
used named constants rather than numbers. Named constants make the code more self documenting, and
allow easier modification of the code. When a named constant is used, the code only needs to be
changed in one location rather than multiple locations. An example of this in the code would be to
increase or decrease the size of the arrays.

Example Named Constants:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE    4
#define STRING_SIZE   10
#define RED           1
#define YELLOW        2
#define GREEN         3
#define BLUE          4
#define BLACK         5
#define WHITE         6
#define MAX_GUESS     12


void makeCode(char secretCode[ARRAY_SIZE][STRING_SIZE])
{
    int i, randColor;
    for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        randColor = 1 + rand() % 6;     //creates a number
        switch(randColor)       //converts number created to a string
        {
            case RED:
                strcpy(secretCode[i], "red");
                break;
            case YELLOW:
                strcpy(secretCode[i], "yellow");       
                break;
            case GREEN:
                strcpy(secretCode[i], "green");       
                break;
            case BLUE:
                strcpy(secretCode[i], "blue");       
                break;
            case BLACK:
                strcpy(secretCode[i], "white");       
                break;
            case WHITE:
                strcpy(secretCode[i], "black");       
                break;
        }
    }
}

void displayGuess(char guessCode[ARRAY_SIZE][STRING_SIZE], int blackPeg, int whitePeg)
{
    int i;
    printf("\nYour Guess\t\t\t\tYour Score\n");
    for(i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%s ", guessCode[i]);
    printf("\t\t");
    for(i=0; i<blackPeg; i++)
        printf("black ");
    for(i=0; i<whitePeg; i++)
        printf("white ");
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

*Note:* The code above would be more efficient if you had an array of color strings and indexed into the
the array using `randColor` as follows:

```
void makeCode(char secretCode[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE])
{
    int i, randColor;
    char *secretCodeColors[] =
        {
            "red",  // Multiple lines used to make it easier to add colors.
            "yellow",
            "green",
            "blue",
            "black",
            "white",
        };

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        randColor = rand() % 6;
        strcpy(secretCode[i], secretCodeColors[randColor]);
    }
}
```

Not only does it make the function shorter, but indexing into the array is faster than the `switch` statement.

@MegaTom is correct; this code would be better using enums or named constants. The string compares are much
less efficient that integer compares.

### Multiple Statements on a Line

To make future modifications easier, there should never be multiple statements on a single line. Let's say
some code needed to be added to each case in the `switch` statement. Each of the cases in the `switch` statement
would then be need to be broken into multiple lines which makes the edit more complex, and can create typos
during the edit. It is much easier to just add another statement by adding a single line, rather than
trying to add it to a single line.

```
            case 1: strcpy(secretCode[i], "red");       break;
            case 1:
                strcpy(secretCode[i], "red");       
                break;
```

Generally it is better to assume that code will need to edited at some time in the future to add features or
fix bugs.

### Prefer `return` over `exit()`

In the case of this program, since there is no error checking, there is no reason to use either `exit()` or `return`.
If there is error handling in the program, the `exit()` function should only be used if the program encounters an
error it can't correct deep in multiple function calls. The `exit()` function should only be used in standalone
programs, never in operating systems code. When using the `exit()` function, use the macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and
`EXIT_FAILURE` that are defined in `<stdlib.h>`.

### Don't Repeat Yourself

When code is repeating itself, it is better to write another function rather than repeating the code. Then the
code only needs to be written and debugged once rather than multiple times. This is known as the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in software engineering.

#### Example:

The following code has loops that repeat:

```
void displayGuess(char guessCode[ARRAY_SIZE][STRING_SIZE], int blackPeg, int whitePeg)
{
    int i;
    printf("\nYour Guess\t\t\t\tYour Score\n");
    for(i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%s ", guessCode[i]);
    printf("\t\t");
    for(i=0; i < blackPeg; i++)
        printf("black ");
    for(i=0; i < whitePeg; i++)
        printf("white ");
    printf("\n\n");
}

void showPeg(int pegCount, char *colorString)
{
    for (i = 0; i < pegCount; i++)
        printf(colorString);
}

void displayGuess(char guessCode[ARRAY_SIZE][STRING_SIZE], int blackPeg, int whitePeg)
{
    int i;
    printf("\nYour Guess\t\t\t\tYour Score\n");
    for(i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%s ", guessCode[i]);
    printf("\t\t");
    showPeg(blackPeg, "black ");
    showPeg(whitePeg, "white ");
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

### Decrease Function Complexity

Another software engineering principle is the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). 
A function should only be responsible for one action; this makes each function easier to read, write, debug and
use multiple times. It is much better to write smaller more concise functions that can be used in multiple
places and only need to be debugged once. The functions `codeCheck()` and `main()` would both benefit from
applying this principle.

### General Comments

The program should guide the user better. It's not clear what the input should be; there should be
prompts for each input. The program might be more fun if the user could enter colors rather than
numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed and clear answer. I m grateful to you. @pacmaninbw

Comment: I think that in this case the "magic numbers" were better than the consents. Defining a constant and only using it once seams like a bad idea. The array approach is definitely better, so +1.

Answer (score 3):

Good job on the code. This is better then I did the first time I tried this problem. But I do see three big problems:

#### 1. Stores codes as strings

I think that it would be best to use a number/enum for the color, not a string. This will use less memory and simplify comparing later, as well as basically fixing problem 2.

#### 2. Silently fails on invalid colors

As your code stands, a player may put in invalid colors and will not get a warning. So if i guess `bleu purple gray orange`, it will say I got nothing, and continue. I think it would be better to tell the user that they are guessing invalid colors. (This is made even worse by the fact that the user is not told what colors are good in the first place.) If you validate as they enter the colors that they entering valid colors, that can fix the problem.

#### 3. Case sensitive

`Red RED Green Black` will fail the comparison the same way as above, because you use `strcmp`, not `strcmpi`.

Comment: strcomp will not compile.

Comment: @pacmaninbw typo, sorry. Error has been fixed in edit.

Comment: What's `strcmpi`?  It's not part of Standard C.

Comment: @TobySpeight https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strcmpi-function-in-c/

Comment: ... which clearly states ***Note: This is a non-standard function that works only with older versions of Microsoft C.***

Answer (score -3):

You should replace your `#define`s with an enum, defines just copy and paste stuff, enums are actually part of the language.

Also, your spacing makes it a bit more difficult to read, but I've seen much worse.

Comment: This seems to attempt to comment on one of the answers, rather than answer the question at the top of this page. Please don't use the "Post Your Answer" button to submit content which is not in reply to the original question.

Comment: I was talking about the users example code...

Comment: That doesn't make sense; there are no `#define`s in the question.

Comment: It was general style suggestions based on his code... You're acting autistic are you struggling to understand what I'm saying? how can I help?

Comment: Explaining which `#define`s exactly you want them to replace with enums would definitely clarify this answer. I still can't see any `#define`s in the code in the question so my best guess is still that you are talking about code in another answer, which then should of course be a comment on that answer instead of a separate answer to the original question.